# jolt transformation for the match

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to use jolt transformation to check if data is matching or not.

**Input**:

```json
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206180",
      "flowMapNodeType": "MAIN_DASHBOARD_NODE",
      "name": "WebFrontEnd",
      "viewPermission": true,
      "agentUp": false
    },
    {
      "id": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206183",
      "flowMapNodeType": "MAIN_DASHBOARD_NODE",
      "name": "AccountManagement",
      "viewPermission": true,
      "agentUp": false
    },
    {
      "id": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206188",
      "flowMapNodeType": "MAIN_DASHBOARD_NODE",
      "name": "PerLoanServices",
      "viewPermission": true,
      "agentUp": false
    },
    {
      "id": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206182",
      "flowMapNodeType": "MAIN_DASHBOARD_NODE",
      "name": "PolicyServices",
      "viewPermission": true,
      "agentUp": false
    },
    {
      "id": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206184",
      "flowMapNodeType": "MAIN_DASHBOARD_NODE",
      "name": "BizLoanServices",
      "viewPermission": true,
      "agentUp": false
    },
    {
      "id": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206185",
      "flowMapNodeType": "MAIN_DASHBOARD_NODE",
      "name": "BalanceServices",
      "viewPermission": true,
      "agentUp": false
    },
    {
      "id": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206186",
      "flowMapNodeType": "MAIN_DASHBOARD_NODE",
      "name": "SessionTracking",
      "viewPermission": true,
      "agentUp": false
    }
  ],
  "sourceNode": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206183",
  "targetNode": "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206184"
}
```

If `sourceNode` is matching with `node.id` in `nodes` subarray then a new field will be added `sourceNodeName` which is the `node.name` field for the same `id`. Similarly `targetNode` is matching with `node.id` in node subarray then a new field will be added `targetNodeName` which is the `node.name` field for the same `id`.

**Expected output** for this input:

```json
{
  "sourceNodeName" : "AccountManagement",
  "targetNodeName" : "BizLoanServices"
  "sourceNode" : "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206183",
  "targetNode" : "Type:APPLICATION_COMPONENT, id:206184"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following tranformation :

```json
[
  { // add keys to the objects, which are under "nodes" array, with "id" values  
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "nodes": {
        "*": {
          "*": "@1,id.&"
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*Node": { // loop only within the "sourceNode" and "targetNode" attributes
        "*": {
          "@(2,&)": { "name": "&3&" } // &3 : Bring the key name after going 3 levels up
        },
        "@": "&" // key-value pair for the upper nodes, eg. "sourceNode" and "targetNode"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros, really appreciate your support!